# Calling system cmd using popen in CGI script

Tags: c, linux, cmd, cgi

Trying to execute the `CGI script` which contains `popen()` to execute the cmd. Even though `popen` return valid pointer but it fails to do desired operation.

Command I want to execute `lsblk`,`insmod` etc

```
void cmd_execute(char *cmd, char *buff, int len)
{
    FILE *f = popen(cmd,"r");
    if (NULL == f){
        printf("<p> popen failed");
        return;
    }
    fread(buff,len,1,f);
    pclose(f);

    printf("<p> buff: %s",buff);
}
```

**HTML Content:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#4a7d49">
<form ACTION="http://localhost/cgi-bin/run.cgi" METHOD="POST" target="display_page">
<input type="submit" value="List Drivers"></form>
<br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried the same for `ls` cmd I got the desired result. But other commands are failing. I am trying this in `rhel6.4`. I tried changing permission using `su -s` and `runuser -l` in **cmd argument** but it doesn't help. I was getting error like ***could not open session***. Let me know if there are better ways to do same.

Comment: Put aside the fact that it is _extremely_ dangerous to run things like `insmod` from CGI context, the CGI daemon user probably doesn't have the required permissions to execute. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @IshayPeled  Need to update some of storage drivers of the server. I have cmd line utility which does the same. But, I need to achieve same using browser also. I chose CGI script  but stuck here.

Comment: Utility generates xml file which contains driver's information. But, when I am trying to generate same xml using CGI script. I am getting issues.

Comment: In that case I would _STRONGLY_ recommend abstracting your logic - don't allow excessive priviliges to the CGI script runner, rather use a server run as root on your system, accepting requests to do only the specific actions you need and communicate with that server with your CGI script

Comment: As I said, I have cmd line utility say **du** which accepts some arguments. which will list down all drivers and write into xml . Again I am reading the xml and showing in web-browser. currently, Failing to generate xml file using **du** cmd.

Comment: `popen(3)` **MUST BE CLOSED** with `pclose(3)`, that `wait(2)`s for the child process to finish.

Comment: Yes !! That is mistake !! Actual code contains `pclose`

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your posted code:

1. so it cleanly compiles
2. and adding error checking
3. EDIT: changed `fclose()` to `pclose()`
4. EDIT: added call to `wait()` for child process to finish

This is the result:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), popen(), pclose(), fread()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

// EDIT: added next two header files for 'wait()'
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>




void cmd_execute(char *cmd, char *buff, size_t len)
{
    FILE *f = popen(cmd,"r");
    if (NULL == f)
    { // then popen failed
        perror( "popen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size_t byteCount = fread(buff,len,1,f);
    if( 0 >= byteCount )
    { // then fread failed
        perror( "fread failed" );
        pclose(f);
        wait( NULL );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    pclose(f);
    wait( NULL );

    printf("<p> buff: %s\n<\\p>",buff);
} // end function: cmd_execute


int main( void )
{
    char *command= "lsblk";
    char buffer[100];

    cmd_execute( command, buffer, 100 );
} // end function: main
```

I then ran it on my system:

ubuntu linux 14.04

Which outputs:

```
<p> buff: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 
<\p>
```

Note: the third line of the output does contain some 'non ascii' characters which may be creating a problem with your browser.

You may want to add a call to `printf()` after each call to `perror()` to display error messages on the browser window.

Comment: `lsblk` is not privileged, did `insmod` work for you?

Comment: It works for me as well !! But I face issue when I try the same using web-browser. Apache(webserver) will not have all permission.

Comment: you can easily modify the `main()` function to retrieve parameters sent from the browser and use those parameters rather than the hardcoded command used in the answer.

Comment: The setup/configuration files for the server will have a "very" limited number of external commands that are allowed to be executed.  This is to protect the server (and its' environment) from attack.

Comment: I'm not going to run `insmod()` as I do not want to be inserting any module into my kernel.

Comment: I dont want to run insmod and lsblk directly.  It will be taken care by some other utility (cmd line). In order to run the utility, I face the issue. I too tried same in Ubuntu and it worked for me but actual requirement is in Rhel.

Comment: `popen(3)` **MUST BE CLOSED** with `pclose(3)`, that `wait(2)`s for the child process to finish.

Comment: @LuisColorado,  Your right, my oversight.  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Su(1)` is a command that must be run interactively.  It opens `/dev/tty` to be able to ask for a password, and, as you are running it in a session without control terminal (all daemon sessions are non-terminal) the `open(2)` of `/dev/tty` fails (with that precise error)

The solution is to use other means of passing the password to `su(1)`. Read its documentation to see if there's an alternative way to pass it the right password. Or to command it to not ask for a password.

By the way, and unrelated to this, but `popen(3)` **must be closed with `pclose(3)`** and not with `fclose(3)`. This is because pclose kills the child and waits for it to terminate, instead of letting it run with the communication channel closed.

One last thing: I don't know the case of your container, but some don't allow you to spawn new processes, so be careful.  I think this is not your case.

Comment: I tried giving permission to `apache`  using `visudo` and tried to run the command but I get the error _"unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted"_

Comment: Check the doc of sudo.  It has plenty of possibilities.